# Invalid Argument Exception , Driver [propel] not Supported in Laravel with using Propel ORM

Tags: php, laravel, propel2

I changed laravel default Authentication Driver **eloquent** to **propel** with the use of the instructions given in below link .

https://packagist.org/packages/propel/propel-laravel

*auth.php*

```
'driver' => 'propel',

'model' => 'MstUser',
```

*MstUser.php*

```
<?php

use Base\MstUser as BaseMstUser;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

/**
 * Skeleton subclass for representing a row from the 'mst_user' table.
 *
 *
 *
 * You should add additional methods to this class to meet the
 * application requirements.  This class will only be generated as
 * long as it does not already exist in the output directory.
 *
 */
class MstUser extends BaseMstUser implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

But It still gives me the following error :

[image]

I m using laravel 5. Any help regarding this problem would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: have you add does: `Propel\PropelLaravel\GeneratorServiceProvider::class`,
`Propel\PropelLaravel\RuntimeServiceProvider::class` to config/app.php ?

Comment: Sorry .. I added that part..  :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the bundle documentation you have to add:

```
Propel\PropelLaravel\GeneratorServiceProvider::class,
Propel\PropelLaravel\RuntimeServiceProvider::class,
```

to the:

```
config/app.php
```

to the `providers` array.